# Rename project folder | Custom Xcode 6 template

Tags: xcode, templates

Xcode by default creates a new project directory as follows:

```
MyProject*
—>MyProject
—>MyProjectTests
—>MyProject.xcodeproj
```

Is there a way to rename MyProject*'s folder using a custom Xcode 6 template? I am trying to achieve the following below renaming MyProject to src:

```
MyRepoFolder
    ->src*
         ->MyProject
         ->MyProjectTests
         ->MyProject.xcodeproj
    ->external
         ->Resources
```